# How to create a hook for custom URL schemes?

Tags: ios

I have a custom URL scheme for my app. When the user goes to my app's browser page and has the app installed I redirect them to the custom url scheme i.e. `myapp://dosomething?ref=117`

This loads up my app and is working fine.

**Question**

Inside my app how do I intercept that the app got opened by the custom URL? I want to intercept `dosomething?ref=117` and open a particular screen.

Comment: See the docs for `UIApplicationDelegate`.

Comment: @Birdy Thanks for deleting your most recent question while I was writing up a length answer (*makes mental note not to try to help anymore*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle any url by the following method in `AppDelegate`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

below is an example of how to extract the parameters of an url

```
- (NSDictionary*)parseURLParameters:(NSURL*)url
{
    NSArray *keyValues = [[url query] componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];

    NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    for (NSString *keyValue in keyValues)
    {
        NSArray *components = [keyValue componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];

        NSString *parameter = components[0];
        NSString *value = components[1];

        NSDictionary *dictionary = @{parameter : value};

        [parameters addEntriesFromDictionary:dictionary];
    }

    return parameters;
}
```

which the following code

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"urlexample://host/path?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2&parameter3=value3"];

NSLog(@"parameters of %@:\n%@", url, [self parseURLParameters:url]);
```

generates the log

```
parameters of urlexample://host/path?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2&parameter3=value3:
{
    parameter1 = value1;
    parameter2 = value2;
    parameter3 = value3;
}
```